# SymStore - add multiple files

Tags: windows, pdb-files, symbol-server, symstore

I am trying to add a bunch of `.pdb` files to the symbol server using `symstore.exe`. Not all the `.pdb`'s in the dir, but a selection of them (based on date).

To add them in a single transaction I'm using `symstore ... /f '@filelist.txt'` where `filelist.txt` is a file containing the real `.pdb` one per line - just as the command-line help says:

```
/f File         Network path of files or directories to add.
                If the named file begins with an '@' symbol, it is treated
                as a response file which is expected to contain a list of
                files (path and filename, 1 entry per line) to be stored.
```

(This info exists only in command-line help to `symstore`, not in the corresponding online [help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

This just doesn't work, it stores 0 files. I assume that this feature - adding multiple files from a file list - is just not really implemented.

Does anybody have success adding a list of files in a single transaction with `symstore.exe`?

Comment: Have you found out, how to do it?

Comment: 3 years later microsoft docs still haven't been updated (i have just made a pull request with change).  Your post helped me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I have figured that out. The feature with *@* and the response file is actually supported.

After using the symstore's */o* switch for debugging output I have noticed a weird character *ÿþC* in the error output

```
PS C:\Development\symstore add /f @C:\temp\dllsAndPdbsToAdd.txt /s C:\temp\symstore\ /t AwesomeProject 
SYMSTORE MESSAGE: 0 alternate indexers registered
SYMSTORE MESSAGE: LastId.txt reported id 8
SYMSTORE MESSAGE: Final id is 0000000008
SYMSTORE ERROR: Class: Internal. Desc: Failed to index C:\Development\AwesomeProject\ÿþC. Line: 169. Error 32
```

So I changed **encoding** of the @C:\temp\dllsAndPdbsToAdd.txt file in Notepad++ to **ANSI** and it worked.

Comment: To store a file in a compatible encoding one can use following PS command "$DllsPaths |Out-File C:\temp\dlls.txt -Encoding ascii"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By now I've already worked it around (by adding all files in a folder), but this is still valuable. And another good example of people making standard feature their own way (which proves worse than the usual way).

Comment: Looks like the UTF-8 BOM.